# Nuxt export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt with Typescript. I create a following component:

```
<template>
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label" v-if="typeof label !== 'undefined'">{{ label }}</label>
        <div class="control">
            <textarea
                v-if="inputType === 'textarea'"
                class="textarea"
                @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
            ></textarea>
            <input
                v-if="inputType === 'input'"
                :type="type"
                class="input"
                @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator"

@Component({})
export default class AppInput extends Vue {
    @Prop({ type: String, required: false, default: "input" })
    inputType!: string

    @Prop({ type: String, required: false })
    label!: string

    @Prop({ type: String, required: false, default: "text" })
    type!: string
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

And then in `@/plugins/components.ts`, I import the component as following:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import AppInput from "@/components/Forms/AppInput.vue"

Vue.component("AppInput", AppInput)
```

When I compile the project with Nuxt, it throws me `export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found` error. Please help!

Comment: Show full error with stacktrace. And where do u import mod

Comment: I don't import `mod`

Comment: `"export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--3-0!../../node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??ref--3-1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./AppInput.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved using the following tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": ["esnext", "esnext.asynciterable", "dom"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmit": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["./*"]
        },
        "types": ["@nuxt/vue-app", "@types/node", "@types/webpack-env"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one of those entries fixed the problem? (My guess is `"target": "esnext"`, from this GitHub comment: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5508#issuecomment-491099733)

Comment: @MasterofDucks Yup that fixed it.

Answer (score 16):

You will need atleast an empty export default script in your vue files to not see this error. If you don't have any export default statement, it gives this error/warning.

```
export default {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything were running fine and sudden it started giving error after

```
npm run dev
```

> "export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in
>   '-!../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ref--2-0!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./default.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&'

I don't know this is a good solution or not but the last change, what I did were,

first div after `<template>` changed to `<div id="my-app">`

So I again reverted the div id to `<div id="app">` and that error gone,

Hope it will help someone.