# bundle 'client' has 221 warnings in typescript in console

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, es6-promise

***I have imported all the .vue and .ts files correctly but also it is showing 121 warnings***

> in
> ./components/project-studio/components/content-step/ProjectStudioContentStep.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
> "export 'PwProjectStudioData' was not found in '~/components/project-studio/lib/PwProjectCreatorTypes'
> friendly-errors 18:58:44
>
> WARN  in
> ./components/project-studio/ProjectStudio.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
> friendly-errors 18:58:44
>
> "export 'PwProjectStudioParams' was not found in
> '~/components/project-studio/lib/PwProjectCreatorTypes'
> friendly-errors 18:58:44
>
> WARN  in ./pages/projects/ProjectsPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
> friendly-errors 18:58:44
>
> "export 'Route' was not found in 'vue-router'
> friendly-errors 18:58:44
> friendly-errors 18:58:44
>
> WARN  in
> ./pages/components/modals/components/ThemeModal.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
> friendly-errors 18:58:44
>
> "export 'ThemeModalParams' was not found in
> '~/services/modal/IModalService'                    friendly-errors
> 18:58:44
> friendly-errors 18:58:44
>
> WARN  in ./node_modules/deasync/index.js
> friendly-errors 18:58:44

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

**Like above I am getting 121 warnings**

*What is the reason that export not found is getting?*

Also I have changed the ES versions in **tsconfig.json**

Present my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "reflect-metadata",
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxtjs/auth-next",
      "types-lib/*"
      
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What was the actual version change, from X to Y ?

Comment: sorry, package or app version?

Comment: At this point, both can be useful IMO.

Comment: Thank you @kissu for at least commenting out, I solved My Issue  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55616248/11824064)

Answer (score 0):

I solved My Issue By changing the tsconfig.json

from This:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "lib": ["ESNext", "ESNext.AsyncIterable", "DOM"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["./*"]
        },
        "types": ["@nuxt/vue-app", "@types/node", "@types/webpack-env"]
    }
}
```

To this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": ["esnext", "esnext.asynciterable", "dom"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmit": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["./*"]
        },
        "types": ["@nuxt/vue-app", "@types/node", "@types/webpack-env"]
    }
}
```

Thanks To [Dammon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9764412/damon) for your answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55616248/11824064)